# How to have repeating headers in sequence per page?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, publishing

I've been re-learning InDesign (currently on MacOS Ventura 13.3.1) and created a test publication at 203 mm x 280mm using a real-life publication of that size as a guideline.

I'm using InDesign 17.4.

So far I've got two headers:

Parent Page A - "YOUR LOCAL NEWS MAGAZINE" "TO ADVERTISE PHONE 555-000-0000"

Parent Page B - "LOCAL NEWS - LOCAL VALUES" - "LOCAL BUSINESSES - LOCAL NEWS"

I currently have applied master pages as A, B, A, B manually but when I was adding new parent pages I noticed the option of Number of Pages is normally 2, but I set it to 4 for one with the following on Parent Page C:

Parent Page C 1 - "YOUR LOCAL NEWS MAGAZINE" "TO ADVERTISE PHONE 555-000-0000"

Parent Page C 2 - "LOCAL NEWS - LOCAL VALUES" - "LOCAL BUSINESSES - LOCAL NEWS"

Parent Page C 3 - "ANYTOWN'S LOCAL NEWS MAGAZINE" - "ANYTOWN'S LOCAL NEWS MAGAZINE"

Parent Page C 4 - "YOUR FRIENDLY LOCAL NEWS MAGAZINE" - "YOUR FRIENDLY LOCAL NEWS MAGAZINE"

However, upon inserting Parent Page C on Page 20 of the magazine, it only applied the first two of the parent pages, even though 4 were set (I added 5 pages with parent page C after Parent Page B via InDesign).

My problem is basically how to have repeating headers that are in sequence - 4 different headers - without creating too many parent pages?

This isn't for public consumption, it's a learning exercise.

If I have done this wrong, please let me know!

Advice appreciated!